# htaccess rewriterule to skip folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

After some changes on my wordpress site, ther are many links out there in the web which cant be accessed anymore. The old urls look like
http://example.com/blog/2017/05/post ans should now show this url
http://example.com/post

I tried this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This doesnt work. Than tried this one.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/././?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This also doesnt work.

Comment: And "doesnt work" means what _exactly_? What happens? Do you get an error? A wrong behavior? Nothing happens? Does the universe implode?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).